# querying a database using a date parameter

Tags: vb.net, oledb, oledbparameter

I am new to Visual Basic as well as Stackoverflow.  I am querying certain fields from a database but receiving an error.  here's my code:

```
Dim fifdate As Date = Now()
fifdate.AddDays(-15)

db.AddParam("collected", "N")
db.AddParam("printed", "Y")
db.AddParam("sent", "Y")
db.AddParam("date", fifdate)




Dim query As String = "Select * from badcheck where fldcollected = 
@collected And fldprinted = @printed And fldsentda = @sent "

'And fldsentdate > @date

db.ExcecuteQuery(query)

CheckedListBox1.DataSource = db.DBDT
```

if i add the commented out section into the query, i get the error "Data type mismatch in criteria expression", but the query works perfectly fine without it.  I know for sure that fldsentdate is set as a date in the database.  any suggestion on how the issue can be fixed?

Comment: `db.AddParam("@collected", "N")`, yada-yada-yada.  Don't make your boolean columns Y-N strings.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I'm working with a database thats already created. For some reason, the creator set those fields as characters and not boolean.

Comment: What happens when you change the commented portion to read, `And fldsentdate > #@date#`  Microsoft Access prefers # to enclose date values

Comment: Gives syntax error. Bout to do more research.

Comment: Odd, is fldSentDate actually a date field within the database?  Try the query direct with # and it should work.  With oledb, I had to use ? where you're using named parameters.  This may have been because I use an older version of Access.

Comment: Not like the # at all. Is it possible to use fifdate directly without adding it as a parameter?

Comment: @JimmySmith You don't use the # sign when using parameters.  The engine will take care of that for you.

Comment: The problem is likely in that `db` thing (probably a SQL "helper"?) and/or the AddParam method. Also, do not add tags to the title, thats what tags are for, read [ask] and take the [tour] since you are new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i was able to fix the problem.  I took the fifdate variable completely out and changed my parameter code to:

```
db.AddParam("date". date.today.AddDays(-15))
```

something was going wrong with fifdate, and I believe it may be due to Now().  i tried using fifdate directly with the query and was receiving the same error.

Comment: A-ha, it was something completely different.  I've had issues with DateAdd and using Now.  I believe the issue was the time piece of the date is more accurate to milli/nano seconds and changes the format of the date (versus what Access is accustomed to)

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. Instead of it giving the variable a date only, it was giving it the date as well as the time and my database variable was only a date.

Comment: the problem is that DateTime vars are immutable; the math operations do not  change the variable but return a **new** variable with the change.  the correct code would be `fifdate = fifdate.AddDays(-15)` or simply `fifdate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-15)`.  You probably want to strip the time off too using `.Date`